# Can unity playerprefs fail to save, and if they do how can I check?

Tags: unity

As the title says I would like to know if playerprefs can fail to save.

If they can, is there some way to check if it save properly / if it failed?

---

Example :

```
if (playerprefsFailed)
{
    Debug.Log("Failed to save playerprefs...");
}
```

---

I found `PlayerprefsException` in the Unity API, however I'm confused on how to use it.

I have also googled if they can fail, but couldn't find any results, however considering there is a exception for it, it can probably fail.

The `PlayerprefsException`is also only thrown on the web player however I would like to know if it can fail, and when, and also how to stop it on a normal pc build.

Comment: Maybe the exception is for retrieving data? I couldn't find anything on failing or checking if it fails either. Sorry.

Comment: It seems that, at least currently, PlayerPrefsException is only thrown in Web Player builds when the preference file exceeds the allotted 1MB size: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefsException.html

Comment: I'd also suggest that in absence of documentation for it, we can assume that PlayerPrefs.Save() will throw an exception if something goes wrong, but I can't test that right now.

Comment: @Joe How would I go about testing it?

Comment: My best idea on that is construct an environment where the default storage location of PlayerPrefs is unwritable, then try saving. Might not be so easy depending on platform.

Comment: @Joe Another question, do you know how long ti takes for a playerpref to save?

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean, it's not asynchronous so if the method returns, saving has finished.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PlayerprefsException will be usually be thrown in web app where 1mb limit gets passed. [Docs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefsException.html)

To check if playerpref got saved use,

```
if(PlayerPrefs.HasKey("myFloat"){
PlayerPref.setFloat("myFloat",myFloatValue);
}else{
//First time initlisation of playerPref
}


if( !PlayerPrefs.HasKey("myFloat") || PlayerPref.getFloat("myFLoat") != myFloatValue){
 Debug.Log("Failed to save playerprefs...");
}
```

Comment: Is it impossible for the PlayerPrefs to save on a non-web game? I mean, lets say the playerprefs file for some reason can't be written to, what will unity do? And how can I alert the player about this issue?

Comment: On Windows standalone, there's no need to expect failure. If an application cannot write something into Registry, then something is very wrong with Windows itself.

Comment: @BiiX correctly pointed by maxim ,that may be the reason why unity not implemented exception for it.

Comment: @MaximKamalov Ah, I see.